# go to a laravel controller using vue js's data

Tags: laravel, routes, vue.js

This is my vue

```
new Vue({
              el: '#notificationMenu',
              data: {
                showModal: false,
                patients: [],
                duepatients: []
              },
                created: function(){
                    this.getPatients();
                    this.addUsers();
                },
                methods: {
                    getPatients: function(){
                           $.getJSON("{{route('api_patients')}}", function(patients){
                            this.patients = patients;
                        }.bind(this));
                        setTimeout(this.getPatients, 1000); 
                    },
                    addUsers: function(){
                      this.$http.get('/govaccine/addUsers', '').then((response) => {

                      }, (response) => {
                        this.formErrors = response.data;
                        });

                       setTimeout(this.addUsers, 10000);                          
                    },sendSMS: function(val){

                      $.getJSON('sendsms/' + val,function(duepatient){
                            this.duepatients = duepatient;
                      }.bind(this));

                    }
                }

            });
```

and this is my html

```
<ul class="notifications-list" v-for="patient in patients">
                        <li class="item no-data">You don't have notifications</li>

                                <!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
                          <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
                            <!--
                              you can use custom content here to overwrite
                              default content
                            -->
                            <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
                          </modal>
                            <a v-on:click="sendSMS(patient.due_date)">
                                <li class="item js-item " data-id="5" >
                                    <div class="details">
                                        <strong>@{{ patient.total}} patients</strong> are due for immunization on @{{patient.due_date}}
                                        <span class="date">{{--  @{{patient.created_at}} --}}</span>

                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="button-default button-dismiss js-dismiss">×</button>
                                </li>
                            </a>
                    </ul>
```

If I loop through vue js data using `v-for` how do i pass the data each loop in {{route('patient.show', parameter)}} so i can put a parameter on it.

or is there anyway to go to the controller and go to the other page?

Answer (score 0):

yes you should use router-link. complete example [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html).
 if I got you question wrong just tell me.